# How to have an R package install and use a custom font

Tags: r, fonts, extrafont, showtext

An R package I'm beginning work on, [ggCheysson](https://github.com/friendly/ggCheysson/) will have a set of custom fonts.

How can I use either the `showtext` or `extrafont` packages to write a function that:

- will install these fonts on the users' system
- use these in graphs and maps?